# Homotopy equivalence in terms of strong deformation retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Visualizing homotopy equivalence maps are not so easy. I thought before that $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are homotopy equivalence iff one can deform $X$ continuously to $Y$. But this is wrong in general. So I tried the following:

**Q1:**

> $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are homotopy equivalence iff one can deform $X$ and $Y$ continuously to a third space $Z$.

or I think equivalently

> $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are homotopy equivalence iff there is a $A\subset X$ such that $A$ be a strong deformation retract of $X$ and $f(A)$ be a strong deformation retract of $Y$

**Q2:** What about this one?

> $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are homotopy equivalence iff there is a $A\subset X$ such that $A$ be a strong deformation retract of $X$ and $f(A)$ be a strong deformation retract of $Y$ (*added after Paul's answer*) **AND** there is a $B\subset Y$ such that $B$ be a strong deformation retract of $Y$ and $g(B)$ be a strong deformation retract of $X$.

Are the above statements true? any proof or counterexample?

Comment: Your conjectures have an imbalance in the variables appearing on the two sides of the "iff". The first conjecture is particularly problematic because $f$ and $g$ don't appear at all in the second half of the "iff".

Comment: The deformation process is probably depend on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: So do you mean, "$X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent iff one can deform $X$ and $Y$ continuously to a third space $Z$"? Actually, what does it mean to continuously deform a _space_? Do you mean something like a fibration over $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Actually $X\simeq Y$ is defined so that " $\exists$ $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ are homotopy equivalence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong. You ask whether the following two conditions are equivalent for two maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$:

1. $f$ and $g$ are homotopy equivalences.
2. There is a $A\subset X$ such that $A$ be a strong deformation retract of $X$ and $f(A)$ be a strong deformation retract of $Y$.

First note that $g$ does not play any role in 2.

Now let $f : S^1 \to *$ be the constant map, where $*$ is a one-point space, and $g : * \to S^1$ be any map.  $f$ is no homotopy equivalence. Now take $A = S^1$. Then you see that 2. is satisfied.

**Update for Q2:**

It is wrong. For $n \le 0$ let $C_n \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the circle with radius $1/3$ and center $(n,0)$, for $n > 0$ let $C_n = \{(n,0)\}$. Define
$$X = Y = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} C_n ,$$
$$f : X \to Y, f(z) = \begin{cases} z + (1,0) & z \in C_n, n  \ne 0 \\ (1,0) & z \in C_0 \end{cases}$$
and $g = f$. This map translates $C_n$ to $C_{n+1}$ if $n \ne 0$ and collapses the circle $C_0$ to the point $C_1$. $f$ is not a homotopy equivalence. Let $A = X$. Then $f(A) = X$ and your condition on $f$ is satisfied. Since $g = f$, also the condition on $g$ is satisfied.

Comment: Is this related to my question?

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: You are right I think. I thought that because homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation it is not important to add this: There is a $B\subset Y$ such that $B$ be a strong deformation retract of $Y$ and $g(B)$ be a strong deformation retract of $X$.

Comment: You should make an update of your question by adding the condition on $g$.

Comment: Anyway, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Oddly no notification for your update appeared in my profile!!